# How to load Json array into separate table rows?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I'm having trouble with displaying my json data correctly. I want to get each products and place them into it's own row.

The problem now is that it places all the data of for example the value "name" into one table row instead of multiple rows.

This is my json data

```
{
 id: "FVFkkD7s8xNdDgh3zAyd",
 name: "AlperKaffe",
 products: [
 {
   id: "0cfBnXTijpJRu14DVfbI",
   name: "Første Kaffe",
   price: "1",
   size: "small",
   quantity: "20 ml"
},
{
   id: "JQadhkpn0AJd0NRnnWUF",
   name: "Anden Kaffe",
   price: "2",
   size: "Medium",
   quantity: "25 ml"
},
{
   id: "UwHHdH8bFxbVHkDryeGC",
   name: "kaffeeen",
   price: "300",
   size: "Small",
   quantity: "23 ml"
},
{
   id: "WiX5h0wFMNkCux9cINYq",
   name: "kaffe modal",
   price: "230",
   size: "Medium",
   quantity: "39 ml"
},
```

this is my Js file which gets the json data. As you can see i'm only working with the "name" value for now

```
  // Jquery getting our json order data from API
  $.get("http://localhost:8888/products", (data) => {    

    let rows = data.map(item => {

      let $clone = $('#frontpage_new_ordertable tfoot tr').clone();

      let productsName = item.products.map(prod => `${prod.name}`);
      $clone.find('.name').html(productsName);

      return $clone;
    });

    // appends to our frontpage html 
    $("#frontpage_new_ordertable tbody").append(rows);


    });
```

this is my html file

```
<body>  
   <table id="frontpage_new_ordertable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td class="name"></td>
        <td class="price"></td>
        <td class="size"></td>
        <td class="quantity"></td>
        <td class="buttons"></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>

  <script src="./itemPage.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must replace 
`let rows = data.map(item => {`
to
`let rows = data.products.map(item => {`

and

```
      let productsName = item.products.map(prod => `${prod.name}`);
```

to

```
      let productsName = item.name;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ab7t1vmf/3/

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your JS snippet seems to be `let rows = data.map(item => { ...`

From what you describe, the JSON data is comprised of 3 keys:

- id
- name
- products

You cannot execute a `map` function directly on a Javascript Object, this function requires an array.

Looking a bit more at your code, I understand you need to display each product on its own row. Thus, you would need to use the `map` function on `data.products` which contains an array (of products).

```js
let rows = data.products.map(item => {
    // ...
    $clone.find('.name').html(item.name);
    // ...
// ...
});
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map